# Google Spreadsheet ImportHTML table

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import the table from this website:

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=917fc37a709542548cc3be077a786c17#data

in this Spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13bfnQP_kgFsB7k3F_6xMxkMI4wW7ukI9TVq-aVZ3TzE/edit#gid=0

and used this function

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=917fc37a709542548cc3be077a786c17#data", "table", 1)
```

The answer is "Imported content is empty". What else do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate option. Use a custom script to load directly the JSON data.

The script to import JSON data with GoogleSheets (credits to Paul Gambill) :
https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

And the data :

```
https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_Landkreisdaten/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&where=1=1&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&orderByFields=OBJECTID%20ASC&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=412
```

Output :

[image: CovidData]

Comment: Thank you, @E.Wiest!

Comment: Hi @E.Wiest The data is imported as intended at first. See [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jFsVFyW0ybhbe-9Oa3_NKHwyMREGOLMKukIJh1qrFFk/edit#gid=0) 

But after a while the data gets lost. It is sayed that the function ImportJSON is unknown. When I open the sheet the data is loaded again.

Comment: Hmm. No problem here. The problem happens when you try to perform operations on the data ? Did you check if the script is associated with the sheet you're working with ? In Google Apps Scripts, "ImportJSON" is the name of my project and "ImportJson" the associated sheet. https://framapic.org/NMucVtxRDrea/nkMTzTB5cftu.PNG If it's OK, maybe we can try to select specifc columns to ease the loading of the data. What are the columns of interest ?

Comment: Hi @E.Wiest I don´t think the problem is related to your URL. I have the same problem with other JSON imports for example in this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qfPAjel9H9M88VYouQtOqycRu71eOj60UVnIxkMxy-k/edit#gid=806799454 with this JSON https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed 

When I run the ImportJSON function I get this message: 
Exception: Attribute provided with no value: url (line 126, file "Code")

Comment: That's odd. From here, the JSON is loaded. https://framapic.org/fXhwA8MVKjfP/LTHm6PIhP6D4.PNG. You can try the original version of the script ( != forked version)  : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/master/ImportJSON.gs

Answer (score 2):

the website you trying to scrape is under JavaScript control. Google Sheets is not capable of importing JS elements. you can test this simply by disabling JavaScript for a given site and what you are left with is able to be scraped. in your case: nothing:

[image: 0]